# Storing an NSMutableArray in AppDegelate - Odd Behaviour - iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, appdelegate

I am declaring an NSMutableArray in my app delegate :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray * passengerLog;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
passengerLog = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then in a later class I access the array as follows (del is a reference to the app delegate) :

```
[del.passengerLog addObject:passenger];
```

The strange thing is that the second time I add an object to this array, this second object is added to the array twice, overwriting the original object that was already in there.

Can anybody help ?

Thanks !

Comment: sorry, I can't understand what you mean by: "the second object is added to the array twice, replacing the original object that was in there." - could you just provide an example of what happens? thanks...

Comment: This may mess with your application logic, but just to try something, change the property to retain instead of copy. Also, you are synthesizing the property correct?

Comment: You're right - changing it to strong seems to stop the crash, but I still have the original problem. Am synthesizing as @synthesize passengerLog.

Comment: Can you post other references to the array?

Comment: My guess is that the "second object" you add to the array is just the first object modified.  Adding an object to an NSMutableArray does not copy it, so any subsequent modifications will be seen when you access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's being added twice and is replacing the first one? In your implementation of the app delegate you should refer to the property:

```
self.passengerLog = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This can be causing the odd behaviour.

EDIT:

Please post some more code so we can help you. Is this the only place where you allocate your array? If yes, are sure that you're using the same instance of your array all the time?

Comment: Mmm - changed to self.passengerLog and now the app crashes at [del.passengerLog addObject]

Comment: In this case the problem is somewhere else, please post some more code so we can help you.

Comment: Just a quick thought, where do you get the reference to your delegate from?

Comment: del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; in the ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: Could you paste the error message you're getting when the application crashes?

Comment: Could you compare references to your mutable array when you're creating it and when you're accessing it from your other class? Are they the same?

Comment: @Piotr Justyna: sorry about the edit - it was not meant: I was thinking this was an answer of mine - but I have promptly deleted my change.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I was thinking about the same thing, but I'm still waiting to see some code to be sure. Cheers!